# Magento 2 :Problem extending Model / ResourceModel

Tags: magento2, resource-model

On a Magento 2 module, I try to extend

- \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option

My File : Mine/Toto/Model/Catalog/Product/Option :

```
namespace Mine\Toto\Model\Catalog\Product;

    class Option extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option
    {

        const OPTION_GROUP_XFILE    = 'xfile';
        const OPTION_TYPE_XFILE     = 'xfile';

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value $productOptionValue,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Factory $optionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Validator\Pool $validatorPool,
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $registry,
                $extensionFactory,
                $customAttributeFactory,
                $productOptionValue,
                $optionFactory,
                $string,
                $validatorPool,
                $resource,
                $resourceCollection,
                $data
            );
        }

        public function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('Mine\Toto\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Option');
            parent::_construct();
        }

        public function getGroupByType($type = null)
        {
        ...
        }

        public function groupFactory($type)
        {
        ...
        }

        public function beforeSave()
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

and, as called in the _construct,

- \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option

My File Mine/Toto/Model/Catalog/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php

```
namespace Mine\Toto\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product;

    class Option extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option
    {

        public function _saveValuePrices(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

The `$this->_init('Mine\Toto\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Option');`
induces an error :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php on line 54
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: `extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option` http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

In your extended resource model file, please try to use the following code,

```
 protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
  }
```

Comment: does Model class extends needs _construc()? I thought it was only block...